# How can I cycle all the vertex that are connected?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

```
In JanusGraph I have 4 nodes.
A(name=alice) -> B
B -> C
C -> D
D -> A

I want to get all the cycles from node A.
```

`g.V().has('name', 'alice').both().both().cyclicPath().path().by('name')`

I can get A->B->A and A->D->A. But I can't get A->B->C->D->A.
I want to get all the path from vertex A to Vertex A.
How can I get it using groovy language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only traversing away from "alice" twice with `both().both()` therefore your path can only be length 3 which would include the "alice" vertex and the two vertices at each step away from "alice" (i.e. `both()` is one step and the second `both()` is the next step). If you want to get do "D" you have add yet another `both()` so that Gremlin can traverse another set of edges and I would think yet another to get back to "alice" from "D".

Or, you could simply use `repeat()`:

```
g.V().has('name', 'alice').
  repeat(both()).emit().times(4).
  cyclicPath().
  path().by('name')
```

Note that I controlled the loop with `times(4)` to define how many steps away from "alice" I wanted to traverse `both()`. You could also use `until()` to control that for a more dynamic way to control loop termination - see [repeat()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step) for more information.